# Storing and modifying several lists in C++

Tags: c++, list

I am starting programming with C++ and I am struggling with implementing an algorithm that access a set of lists in order and performs some deletions in the middle. The number of lists is not known at compilation time.

My question is how can I store these lists (or references to them) so that I can access them most efficiently. Please find below a very simple example of what I want to do for the case of only two simple lists {0,1,2}, and the deleted element being the second in both cases. Thank you in advance.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <list>
using namespace std;

int main(){
    list<int> list1;
    list<int> list2;
    for(int j = 0; j < 3; j++){
        list1.push_back(j);
        list2.push_back(j);
    }

    list<int>::iterator i;

    i = list1.begin();
    advance(i,1);
    list1.erase(i);

    i = list2.begin();
    advance(i,1);
    list2.erase(i);
}
```

Comment: You can put almost anything into a container with dynamic size like `std::vector` or `std::list`. For instance, other vectors and lists.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have an unknown (at compile time) number of elements of the same typ (`std::list` in your example). Your go to solution should be `std::vector`, so `std::vector<std::list<int>>` in your example:

```
int main()
{
    int n = 3; // get at runtime

    std::vector<std::list<int>> lists(n); // n lists

    // for each list
    for(auto& list : lists)
    {
        // populate the list
        for (int i = 0; i < 3; ++i)
        {
            list.push_back(i);
        }
    }

    // for each list
    for (auto& list : lists)
    {
        // remove the element you want

        auto it = list.begin();
        std::advance(it, 1);

        list.erase(it);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

For this, you can make a list of lists.

```
std::list<std::list<int>> my_list;
```

Accessing this list works just like you how access the integers.

```
for(auto l: my_list){
    list<int>::iterator current_iterator = l.begin();
    //Do the rest of your work here
}
```

Answer (score 0):

A `std::list` can hold almost any type (there are of course some requirements, see [here](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/list) for details). It can also hold `std::list<int>`s as elements, that would be

```
std::list< std::list<int> > list_of_lists;
```

Note that your example is a good case for `std::list` (erasing an element in the middle), however in general `std::vector` out-performs `std::list` for most applications due to memory locality. When in doubt make `std::vector` the default and compare.

Comment: Yes, in my real case I have to remove a large amount of (in fact, most of) the elements in the middle of the list, so I thought I should use lists instead of vectors. In any case thank you very much for you suggestion, I may try and compare the results.